# How to use Elliptic Curves Diffie-Hellman with SJCL in JS and OpenSSL in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, sjcl

Using Elliptic-Curves Diffie-Hellman, I want to connect SLCL - JS [(documentation)](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/) on client and OpenSSL - Ruby [(documentation)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html) on server.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135420/elliptic-curve-cryptography-with-sjcl-in-js-and-openssl-in-ruby) but it wasn't really answered properly and it was also not what I am really looking for since it uses `sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(384, 10)` whereas I am hoping of using `sjcl.ecc.curves['c384']` <- NIST

Nevertheless, I still used and modified his code to test because I had problems using `sjcl.ecc.curves['c384']` producing a single public point-key, and this is what I came up with.

```
//Javascript
keypair = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(384, 10);
console.log(keypair.pub._point.toBits()); //Changed from his serialize()
```

This outputs to

```
[-1992414123, 638637875, 1917312913, 73389700, -425224557, 743777818, 970253455, 723842951, -1751664279, 982132367, -1949786746, 1067402923, -869929568, 157928816, 1651634060, 1968161300, -216192372, -1858642177, -1345910998, -2128793177, -1325754797, 143080818, 1868787479, -484135391]
```

Using the output to ruby:

```
#Ruby
pointArr = [-1992414123, 638637875, 1917312913, 73389700, -425224557, 743777818, 970253455, 723842951, -1751664279, 982132367, -1949786746, 1067402923, -869929568, 157928816, 1651634060, 1968161300, -216192372, -1858642177, -1345910998, -2128793177, -1325754797, 143080818, 1868787479, -484135391]

# ugly bit magic to somehow convert the above array into a proper byte array (in form of a string)
pointStr = [(pointArr.map { |i| (i>=0)?('0'*(8-i.to_s(16).length)+i.to_s(16)):("%08X" % (2**32-1+i+1)) }*'').upcase].pack("H*")

#My modified code
pointInt = pointStr.unpack('B*').first.to_i(2) #Convert BitStr to integer
pointBN = OpenSSL::BN.new(pointInt.to_s, 10) #Int to BigNumber (to be used as param below)

group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('secp384r1') #EC Group to be used

client_pub_point = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(group, pointBN)
# ^
# ^ ABOVE'S MY PROBLEM -> OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error: invalid encoding
# ^

#Server EC: code taken and modified from https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3966195 
ec = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
ec.generate_key

pub = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
pub.public_key = client_pub_point

#Compute Shared Key
shared_key = ec.dh_compute_key(pub.public_key)

puts shared_key.unpack('I>*')
```

This 'puts' something like below when original code from [(link)] (https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3966195) above is used

```
3747233514
2683763564
475565567
1087119841
857380668
2490387914
3548975947
2348082236
2093543365
1477205987
4289120093
3330807042
```

That should be it, but just in case here's my test

```
irb(main):113:0> ec = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::EC:0x37f4250>
irb(main):114:0> ec.generate_key
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::EC:0x37f4250>

irb(main):115:0> pub = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::EC:0x374f070>
irb(main):116:0> pub.public_key = ec.public_key
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point:0x37f8090>

irb(main):117:0> pub.public_key.to_bn
=> 7699789176960498967958014210931326569901199635665512831714857096185925821659134057981449113945854620725216613989823482205311316333140754760317456176281271361802541262755346331375041208726203461213190230560617504850860621520632944763
irb(main):119:0> OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(group, pub.public_key.to_bn)
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::EC:0x4029f48>

#The ABOVE FORMAT works, unlike the error I got like the following

irb(main):122:0> pointBN
=> 832312614609895991150696681555479456971598284480953722479085426901428295415600048953528780331647571635767075686130334170313461289491500162782258792834115040597490936949579748064005380309022482780162833924377801386781542770068991521
irb(main):123:0> OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(group, pointBN)
OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error: invalid encoding
```

But comparing the working and the not-working just above, it seems that total number of decimal digits are the same, so I think I'm somewhat on the right track, but I just couldn't really work it out.

For those who might run into this kind of problem, these are my reference codes [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135420/elliptic-curve-cryptography-with-sjcl-in-js-and-openssl-in-ruby) [(2)](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3966195) [(3)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sjcl-discuss/aVgE4fBObuA) [(4)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sjcl-discuss/L-Vk643GoUQ) [(5)](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues/96)

I'm stuck on this for two days now and there seems to be not much written about this on the net, and I couldn't find any other JS library that supports elliptic curve. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "ugly bit magic to somehow convert the above array into a proper byte array" - apparently its not correct.

Comment: Im not sure, i just copied it from the said link. I'm a bit held back by it as well, but I just thought of trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved this problem! :)

I used a different Javascript library. If you're looking on solving similar problem like this, please refer to the other question of mine [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483036/why-is-the-ecc-dh-symmetric-key-of-this-site-different-from-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

> #Server EC: code taken and modified from https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3966195 
>      ec = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
>      ec.generate_key
>      ...

Usually, we just call `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name` with the NID of a well known curve. The NIDs would include:

- `NID_secp160k1`
- `NID_secp192k1`
- `NID_secp224k1`
- `NID_secp256k1`
- `NID_secp384r1`
- `NID_secp521r1`
- other primary field curves
- other binary field curves

I think the complete list of them is available in the OpenSSL sources, `obj_mac.h`:

```
#define SN_secp112r1        "secp112r1"
#define NID_secp112r1       704
#define OBJ_secp112r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,6L

#define SN_secp112r2        "secp112r2"
#define NID_secp112r2       705
#define OBJ_secp112r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,7L

#define SN_secp128r1        "secp128r1"
#define NID_secp128r1       706
#define OBJ_secp128r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,28L

#define SN_secp128r2        "secp128r2"
#define NID_secp128r2       707
#define OBJ_secp128r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,29L

#define SN_secp160k1        "secp160k1"
#define NID_secp160k1       708
#define OBJ_secp160k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,9L

#define SN_secp160r1        "secp160r1"
#define NID_secp160r1       709
#define OBJ_secp160r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,8L

#define SN_secp160r2        "secp160r2"
#define NID_secp160r2       710
#define OBJ_secp160r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,30L

#define SN_secp192k1        "secp192k1"
#define NID_secp192k1       711
#define OBJ_secp192k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,31L

#define SN_secp224k1        "secp224k1"
#define NID_secp224k1       712
#define OBJ_secp224k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,32L

#define SN_secp224r1        "secp224r1"
#define NID_secp224r1       713
#define OBJ_secp224r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,33L

#define SN_secp256k1        "secp256k1"
#define NID_secp256k1       714
#define OBJ_secp256k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,10L

#define SN_secp384r1        "secp384r1"
#define NID_secp384r1       715
#define OBJ_secp384r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,34L

#define SN_secp521r1        "secp521r1"
#define NID_secp521r1       716
#define OBJ_secp521r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,35L

#define SN_sect113r1        "sect113r1"
#define NID_sect113r1       717
#define OBJ_sect113r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,4L

#define SN_sect113r2        "sect113r2"
#define NID_sect113r2       718
#define OBJ_sect113r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,5L

#define SN_sect131r1        "sect131r1"
#define NID_sect131r1       719
#define OBJ_sect131r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,22L

#define SN_sect131r2        "sect131r2"
#define NID_sect131r2       720
#define OBJ_sect131r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,23L

#define SN_sect163k1        "sect163k1"
#define NID_sect163k1       721
#define OBJ_sect163k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,1L

#define SN_sect163r1        "sect163r1"
#define NID_sect163r1       722
#define OBJ_sect163r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,2L

#define SN_sect163r2        "sect163r2"
#define NID_sect163r2       723
#define OBJ_sect163r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,15L

#define SN_sect193r1        "sect193r1"
#define NID_sect193r1       724
#define OBJ_sect193r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,24L

#define SN_sect193r2        "sect193r2"
#define NID_sect193r2       725
#define OBJ_sect193r2       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,25L

#define SN_sect233k1        "sect233k1"
#define NID_sect233k1       726
#define OBJ_sect233k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,26L

#define SN_sect233r1        "sect233r1"
#define NID_sect233r1       727
#define OBJ_sect233r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,27L

#define SN_sect239k1        "sect239k1"
#define NID_sect239k1       728
#define OBJ_sect239k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,3L

#define SN_sect283k1        "sect283k1"
#define NID_sect283k1       729
#define OBJ_sect283k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,16L

#define SN_sect283r1        "sect283r1"
#define NID_sect283r1       730
#define OBJ_sect283r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,17L

#define SN_sect409k1        "sect409k1"
#define NID_sect409k1       731
#define OBJ_sect409k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,36L

#define SN_sect409r1        "sect409r1"
#define NID_sect409r1       732
#define OBJ_sect409r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,37L

#define SN_sect571k1        "sect571k1"
#define NID_sect571k1       733
#define OBJ_sect571k1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,38L

#define SN_sect571r1        "sect571r1"
#define NID_sect571r1       734
#define OBJ_sect571r1       OBJ_secg_ellipticCurve,39L
...
```

---

> #Compute Shared Key
>      shared_key = ec.dh_compute_key(pub.public_key)

There's an example of ECDH on the OpenSSL wiki. I believe Matt Caswell provided it. You can find it at [Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman).

I think the OpenSSL wiki example was also copy/pasted once here: [ECDH secrets generated by BouncyCastle Java API and by OpenSSL are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149271/ecdh-secrets-generated-by-bouncycastle-java-api-and-by-openssl-are-different).

I don't know SJCL or Ruby, so I can't help you.

---

> sjcl.ecc.curves['c384'] <- NIST

I believe you would want `NID_secp384r1` for this, but I don't know Ruby so take it at face value. For a list of named curves to NIDs, see [OpenSSL: openssl/ CHANGES openssl/apps/ ecparam.c openssl/crypto...](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-cvs&m=132983530418592).

---

If you are going to save the key to disk and possibly use it later in a certificate (for example, ECDSA signing), then you will want to set the `OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` flag. The flag simply saves the group parameters by name (for example, `ASN1 OID: prime256v1`) rather than listing all the domain parameters in ASN1 objects (field type, primary or binary field, base point, etc).

You do that with:

```
EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(key, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
```

If you don't set the flag, then you will encounter "no shared ciphers" error when negotiating suites. Here are the symptoms on the client and server:

- Client (s_client):

  - `139925962778272:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 40`
  - `139925962778272:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:`
- Server (s_server):

  - `140339533272744:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1353:`

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. As much as I would want to shift to C language, I already have some other working parts of this project I have in Ruby. I'll try to look for the equivalent Ruby methods of what you've written. I just still hope I could finally be able to connect it with the client on the other end with Javascript.